# object required error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form that I created with 2 text input boxes and a submit button in excel.

I need to basically take the data that the user input into my 2 form fields and then put it into cells in excel.

Here is the code I have but for some reason I am getting an Object required error even though I set my variables.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim startPoint As String, endPoint As String

    Set startPoint = ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextBox1").Result
        If startPoint = "" Then Exit Sub
            Worksheets(1).Range("A1").value = startPoint
    Set endPoint = ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextBox2").Result
        If endPoint1 = "" Then Exit Sub
            Worksheets(1).Range("A4").value = endPoint

    m1 = Worksheets(1).Range("D4").value
    km1 = m1 / 1000
    MsgBox "Your starting point is " & startPoint & vbCrLf _
        & vbCrLf & "It is " & m1 & "m" & " (" & km1 & "km) from " & endPoint

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code (assuming your form is UserForm1):

```
startPoint = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
If startPoint = "" Then Exit Sub
Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = startPoint

endPoint = UserForm1.TextBox2.Text
If endPoint = "" Then Exit Sub
Worksheets(1).Range("A4").Value = endPoint
```

Answer (score 1):

You only use `Set` to pass an `Object` to a variable excluding the actual value or result.

Example:

```
Set startpoint = Me.Textbox1.Value
Range("A1").Value = startpoint
```

This will give you the object required error since `Me.Texbox1.Value` does not refer to a valid `object` but a `Value`.

Proper way:

```
Set startpoint = Me.Textbox1
Range("A1").Value = startpoint.Value
```

In the above, you pass the `Textbox1` object to `startpoint`.
And then pass the `Value` of that `object` to the target range.

Another way is to directly pass the `Value` to a variable.

```
startpoint = Me.Textbox1.Value
Range("A1").Value = startpoint
```

No need to use `Set` to get since you are not passing an `Object` but a `Value`.
Hope this helps.